# Code crashes with message : Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, anaconda, conv-neural-network

I am clueless as to why I keep getting this error. I used the same CNN model to train MNIST dataset, but I did not face any issue previously. Out of nowhere, I start getting this issue. I haven't installed any libraries during that time frame, my gpu drivers are up to date.
I also did a fresh install of CUDA 10.1 with cuDNN v8.0.4 (for cuda 10.1), using tensorflow version 2.3.0 and Anaconda version 2020.07

This is the model:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,filter_size1,strides=(1,1),input_shape=(None,None,1), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Conv2D(43,filter_size2,input_shape=(None,None,64), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Conv2D(29,filter_size2,input_shape=(None,None,43), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Conv2D(19,filter_size2,input_shape=(None,None,29), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(Conv2D(10,filter_size2, input_shape=(None,None,19), data_format='channels_last'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Activation(activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, to_categorical(y_train), epochs=5)
```

This is the error I've been getting:

```
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-8765eb732021> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train, to_categorical(y_train), epochs=5)

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    838         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    839         # stateless function.
--> 840         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    841     else:
    842       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2827     with self._lock:
   2828       graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2829     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2830 
   2831   @property

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs, cancellation_manager)
   1841       `args` and `kwargs`.
   1842     
-> 1843     return self._call_flat(
   1844         [t for t in nest.flatten((args, kwargs), expand_composites=True)
   1845          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1921         and executing_eagerly):
   1922       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1923       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1924           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1925     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    543       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    544         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 545           outputs = execute.execute(
    546               str(self.signature.name),
    547               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\.conda\envs\GPUEnv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node sequential_2/conv2d_9/Conv2D (defined at <ipython-input-23-8765eb732021>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4211]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
I loaded a model that I previously saved, and it seems to be working fine. But besides that model, no model is being executed.

Comment: Make sure you have only one kernel running

Comment: @NicolasGervais, Yes I have only one active kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched for quite a while on GitHub pages, and found out this chunk of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config)
```

As far as I can understand, it is limiting the amount of GPU memory being used. Please do correct me if I'm wrong, might help someone else facing the same issue.